# avoid unwanted scaling for image in parallax scrolling effect

Tags: javascript, html, css, parallax

here is my demo, as you can see the image scale so the margin:top of the parallax wrapper can't be dynamic.

demo : http://jsfiddle.net/KsdeX/12/

```
.wrapper-parallax {
    margin-top: 150px;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}
```

what are the possible solution for this? max width for the img?

Answer (score 1):

yes, i dont really understand whats the problem here, you can just do

```
img {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
max-width: 350px;
z-index: -1;
background: cyan;
```

}

and then the image wont scale anymore.. ?

Comment: not bad, when the windows size becoming smaller, can the img became more to center?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you wanted..

```
I had to use some javascript in this code, and declared some ids to make it easy for me :p
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KsdeX/13/)

Comment: can you control the content margin? when the img shrink, there's a white space left between the header and the content..

Comment: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/KsdeX/14/)  
While reducing size at some point your div won't move(leaving whitespace at top).. that'll be because of `.wrapper-parallax`'s `margin-top`